# GetTempPathA function crashes after printing result

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get the temporary folder of a user on Windows by using the [GetTempPathA function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
    LPSTR ptcPath = new CHAR(MAX_PATH);

    GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH - 1, ptcPath);

    std::cout << "Temporary path : " << ptcPath << std::endl;
```

So the program outputs correctly the temporary path but crashes right after that (it's part of a big code).

I'm sure the crash comes from GetTempPathA since the program works fine if I comment that line.

It crashes whatever the size I allocate or put instead of `MAX_PATH - 1` except for all the values under `<size of the path> + 1` that prints gibberish.

I put `MAX_PATH - 1` as a value because it solved the problem for someone else on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vc.language/QeSkE9WngVc/flwZZ8CzZbEJ).

Comment: Well I don't know if I should delete it though, even though it's being downvoted it's a stupid typo that anyone who doesn't pay attention as I did can easily miss (and even post about it before going like "Wait THAT'S F*CKING PARENTHESIS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
new CHAR(MAX_PATH)
```

you allocate space for a *single* `CHAR` and initialize that one to `MAX_PATH`. That means your call to `GetTempPathA` will write out of bounds of that single `CHAR` element, leading to *undefined behavior*.

You probably mean

```
new CHAR[MAX_PATH]
```

which allocates an array of `MAX_PATH` elements.

Comment: ...Well I feel like a dumb** now.

Comment: And of course `MAX_PATH` is 260 so it won't even fit into a single `char` (on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, where should we begin?

the main issue is the expression

```
new CHAR(MAX_PATH);
```

this does **not** allocate an array of characters, but only one, singular character with the **value** of `MAX_PATH`.

so in a sense, it as if you've written down

```
char* c = new char(static_cast<char>(MAX_PATH))
```

but instead, simply use the fact that `std::string` has to keep its internal buffer contiguous:

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.resize(MAX_PATH + 1);
const auto new_size = GetTempPathA(buffer.size(), &buffer[0]); //deal with newsize == 0
buffer.resize(new_size);
```

anyway, it is worth mentioning that `new`,`new[]`,`delete`,`delete[]` are not used anymore in modern C++. opt for `std::vector` and `std::string` for raw memory for IO operations, and `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` for all the rest.

Comment: Might as well initialize `buffer` to the right size.